# Laptop showing connected but no internet access

Tags: windows

I have a laptop that I used to connect to internet with it, but today when I opened it, it seemed to be connected but I couldn't open google Or Mozilla nor I.E.
What is wrong? I reset winsock and TCP/IP with cmd still nothing???????

Comment: What `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ping www.google.com` give you?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you've already checked if you use a proxy for any changes. Another possibility is that it might be a firewall issue, though *why* the issue should occur on a working computer, I'm unsure... perhaps some entries were lost.

Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and type "firew" and click the entry for the *Windows Firewall with Advanced Security* CPL to open it. Check that there are *Inbound* and  *Outbound* rules to *Allow* the applications. See the example below for an *Inbound* rule. If the rules are missing, try creating them for one application to see if that resolves the issue, and, if so, create 'em all.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Check ir your DNS server is available (CMD ipconfig /all -> DNS) try to ping to that IP or just try to reach http://172.217.18.131 or any other IP address instead of domain. If you can access the IP address change your DNS server address, to like google's: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4.
2. Check if you're getting your IP settings from DHCP server.

> Open CMD, type "ipconfig /release" then "ipconfig /renew"

If you will get the IP parameters that means that your DHCP server is set and is working fine. If no it means that your DHCP server is not set up(you need to find out your network, mask, gateway and set it in static way) or it may be broken.

3. If you get the IP parameters and it still aren't able to reach any website check if your router is available (ipconfig /all -> gateway) try to ping to that IP address
4. If you can ping to router but can't ping to any external IP (like 8.8.8.8) - Login to your router and try to ping to 8.8.8.8 from the router itself. If it will work it will mean that's something wrong with your NAT settings.
5. If you can't ping to any external IP from router check if default gateway is set on router, if it's try to ping to it. If it's not working contact your ISP, it's their problem.